# How to access asset file in pure dart package?

Tags: json, flutter, file, dart, assets

I wrote a dart package which is being used by my flutter application.
Inside the dart package I want to store some static data in a json file which I want to read from the dart package code.

However I can't find a way to access asset files directly from a dart package. Using the `File(path).readAsString()` only works for dart console applications and using the `rootBundle` only works for flutter packages/applications.

**My question is: How can I access this file which is stored in the dart package assets directly from the pure dart package?**

In a flutter package I would simply make the file available via pubspec.yml like this

```yaml
flutter:
   assets:
      - lib/assets/b737.json
```

But I could not find a similar solution for a pure dart package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary of solutions

After long research and nice help from the community this feature simply doesn't seem to exist.

But there are workarounds:

### Load from Flutter project and pass read string to dart package

Load the asset file from the flutter project via rootBundle.loadString() and specify the asset file in the flutter pubspec.yaml and pass the string data to the dart package. Check ch271828n's answer for details

### Make it a flutter package

An easy solution is to convert the pure dart package to a flutter package. Then it's not pure dart anymore, but that doesn't always hurt. Especially, when the package is used inside another flutter project/package.

### Save the raw data in a variable

Instead of providing asset files and reading the content at runtime, you can also directly safe the asset file content to a static const variable. For bigger assets however this might slow down your IDE if it indexes hundrets of thousands of lines from the assets. Excluding these files from the analyzer might help: analysis_options.dart

```yaml
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - '**/assets/data/**'
```

### aspen package

You can also checkout the aspen package which assists with the previous solution. You specify the paths of the assets and via code generation the contents of these files are then saved to variables which are directly available from the code.

```dart
part 'assets.g.dart';

// @Asset is an annotation from package:aspen that marks the asset to be packed.
@Asset('asset:my_package/web/my-asset.txt')
// We create a const (it must be const!) value that holds the generated asset content.
const myTextAsset = TextAsset(text: _myTextAsset$content);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is "impossible" at the first look, because the Dart package can be used anywhere - e.g. used in a non-Flutter environment. Then there is really no way to find it.

However, there is a workaround: The [inverse of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Example code:

```
// pure dart package

abstract class AbstractAssetFileFetcherService {
  String getAssetFileContent(String assetName);
}

AbstractAssetFileFetcherService? service;

void myFunctionThatUsesAssetFile() {
  var myFirstFileContent = service.getAssetFileContent('my-first-file-name.png');
  var mySecondFileContent = service.getAssetFileContent('my-second-file-name.json');
  // ... use the file content happily ...
}
```

And in the Flutter package which you want to use the pure-dart package:

```
void main() {
  service = AssetFileFetcherService(); // or use other IoC methods such as the `GetIt` Dart package
  myFunctionThatUsesAssetFile();
}

class AssetFileFetcherService extends AbstractAssetFileFetcherService {
  String getAssetFileContent(String assetName) {
    return rootBundle.loadString(assetName); // just use any normal method. you are in Flutter environment here.
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Asset files of Flutter may not exist anywhere in the disk path - it can be compressed in the apk (android) file for example. In addition, you may not have sufficient permissions to do so.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling

> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, IoC is a workaround, but not a real solution to the problem. Actually, I don't understand why it's not working. Independent of the environment where the dart package is used, if the asset files are located inside the lib folder, it shouldn't be hard to locate them if you know the relative path from the project root...

Comment: @tmaihoff Indeed, no. Asset files of Flutter may not exist anywhere in the disk path - it can be compressed in the apk (android) file for example. In addition, you may not have sufficient permissions to do so.

Comment: @tmaihoff In addition, "During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime." (by https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling), so it is in a special bundle.

Comment: @tmaihoff Wait a bit - is this link useful? ---> https://medium.com/@wangdazhitech/flutter-read-asset-file-and-write-to-app-path-42115d4ec1b6

Comment: Not really, in the link they also use the flutter import `import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;`

Comment: Maybe this is just not implemented. I thought this is very basic feature, but apparently not

Comment: @tmaihoff I do hope so but imho maybe no. Assets are quite complicated features. They are not some normal files that are on disk. You can learn more by searching how android and ios handle assets (e.g. how they handle an image or an arbitrary file that bundles together with the app).

Comment: @tmaihoff If you feel the answer useful, you can click the "accept" ;)

Comment: Sure, will do. Just want to use the full bounty time in case someone else comes across this question with a solution. This topic is a bit unsatisfying but having the answer "not possible" is still better than not knowing an existing solution

Comment: @tmaihoff Sure. I am also interested in this question and happy to see if someone finds out the solution

Comment: I have a PURE_DART-package. But I am not able to read its assets from a Flutter-project. How are the assets referenced in the Flutter-project? This does not work:, variations also do not work: `flutter: assets: - packages/PURE_DART/` Is there a complete, working example available?

Answer (score 0):

Acounding the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) you should use the rootBundle to load your json:

```
String   jsonString =  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/b737.json');
```

If you are using it inside an Widget its recomended to user [DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultAssetBundle/of.html)

```
String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle
      .of(context)
      .loadString("assets/b737.json");
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. Your solution only works for flutter packages. I need to access asset files from and inside a pure dart package. I updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: maybe is an problem locating the packages path from inside. Look at this tutorial if it helps: https://medium.com/@codetreeglobal/reading-a-text-file-in-dart-4cc929098cba

Comment: yeah I know that approach. This only works for console applications where you can access the computer file system. When you try that inside a dart package project the file cannot be located

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final stringData = await File('data.json').readAsString();
final data = json.decode(stringData);
```

Comment: This does not work for dart packages which are used in a flutter application. Files are not found this way. If you have minimial working example though, please share it

Comment: I used this on a non-flutter projecr. Before I provided this code, I tested by creating a main.dart and demo.json and it worked by running the main function.

Comment: Yes, in non-flutter projects this works. But I need a solution which works in a pure dart package inside a flutter package

Answer (score 0):

As an unintended alternative to the `aspen` package, I wrote a [`resource_importer`](https://pub.dev/packages/resource_importer) package that also uses code generation to store data as literals. (I perhaps wouldn't have written it if I were aware of `aspen` at the time.  Alas.)

Usage is a bit different; assets are specified via `pubspec.yaml`.  For example:

```yaml
resource_importer:
  resources:
    myImage: 'assets/image.png'
    myLicense:
      path: 'LICENSE'
      type: String
```