# Flutter using pure-dart package, which accesses its own Assets

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies

**Background**

Trying to use a pure-dart package from a Flutter-project.

The pure-dart package basically is a Database. It reads its own JSON-assets and answers to queries.

The Flutter-project accesses the pure-dart package as a database: `PureDart.tellMe("something")`.

The Flutter-project is not accessing the assets of the pure-dart project directly.

**Tried**

Inversion-Of-Control seemed interesting, but it does not for work me. The error is always `Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/BLA.json" (404)`.

I tried various variations of defining the assets.

[How to access asset file in pure dart package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849867/how-to-access-asset-file-in-pure-dart-package)

**Question**

How to define the assets of the pure-dart package, and where? Do they need to be defined in the Flutter-project and the pure-dart package?

Is there a working example out there demonstrating how to achieve this?

There are a few blog posts and questions on SO regarding this topic, but none actually lead to a working example.

Thanks.

Comment: Inversion of control just means that the *consumer* of your package is responsible for providing assets and for providing callbacks (or some other mechanism) to access those assets.  Inversion of control does not allow your package to provide its own assets.

Comment: The linked question provides other approaches (such as embedding assets as literals in code, either manually or via code generation).  You say that you "tried various variations of defining the assets" but don't describe how those other approaches didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems not plausible way to make a pure-Dart package accessing its JSON-assets, when used consumed by a Flutter project, the alternative is to turn the pure-Dart package into a Flutter project.

The Database-Flutter project needs to access its own assets as follows:

```dart
var json = jsonDecode(
  await rootBundle.loadString(
  'packages/DATABASE_PACKAGE_NAME/assets/asset.json'
  )
);
```

Its `pubspec.yaml` defines the assets as usual:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

The Flutter project consuming the Database-Flutter project simply adds it as a dependency.

Comment: Why would embedding the data as a string literal be "not plausible"?  It might not be *preferable* for your taste, but it is a valid and workable approach.

Comment: You are asking a question that you made up by introducing your own context. It has no relevance to the use case I described in my initial questions.

Comment: How is it different?  Ultimately you want your package to include data from an external file, yes?

Comment: None of your comments answered answered the original question which mentioned a JSON file. I am well aware of various possible solutions and approaches. Please leave now.

Comment: A JSON file is a text file.  A text file can be embedded as a `String` literal that you then could call `json.decode` on.  But fine, if you're unwilling to accept advice, so be it.

Comment: I am well aware of various possible solutions and approaches. Please leave now.